# Retrieve data writed by a specific user using angular2 and firebase

Tags: firebase, angular

just wondering how to retrieve data writed by a specific user using angular2 and firebase without using filter and map. if there is a way.

Comment: Have you looked at firebase query documentation https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries?

Comment: didnt read the doc carefully  , many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could use the `equalTo` query:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://something.firebaseio.com/posts');
ref.orderByChild('sender').equalTo('some user').on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

In this case, a `sender` attribute must be present

See this link for more details:

- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html